# Change Laravel DB Connection

Tags: database, laravel, connection

I want to change the DB in my Laravel project. I move to the .env file and changed the db name. But after I changed the db name, the larval project use still the old db. But why?

Comment: What's your `config/database.php` look like?

Answer (score 4):

Write in your terminal

`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: It doesn't work. I make a change in .evn and .evn_example but nothing happens. This project is a copy from another project but I'dont think that is is a problem?

Comment: in that case you have to run 
composer update
command in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The laravel configuration take credentials project get data from .env file 
Please try:

```
    $ composer dump
```

or

```
    $ composer dumpautoload
```

and then try to run the command

```
    $ php artisan config:clear
```

It worked form me when I had the same problem.

If this does not work please delete the content from cache in the directory `bootstrap\cache` and then try the above command again. Please make backup before delete.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to delete the content from the folder

```
project_root_directory/Bootstrap/cache
```

and then try composer dump and try again to run the project.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step.

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache

php artisan route:clear

php artisan route:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Change DB credentials in .env file and Run `php artisan config:cache`.
DB values will be changed right away .